# What do I do if a Google Data Studio bar chart filter makes my legend unorganized?

Tags: bar-chart, looker-studio

I created a bar chart that represents the number of projects per quarter and I added a breakdown dimension called level of change impact (represented by the colorful legend).

**The bar chart**:
[image: The bar chart]

In order for the level of change impact/legend to follow a certain order (0-Empty, 1-Lo, 2-Med, 3-Med/Hi, 4-Hi), I typed in the following code in Secondary sort > New field:

```
CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(level of Change impact, "0-Empty") THEN 5
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(level of Change impact, "1-Lo") THEN 4
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(level of Change impact, "2-Med") THEN 3
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(level of Change impact, "3-Med/Hi") THEN 2
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(level of Change impact, "4-Hi") THEN 1
  ELSE 0
END
```

I also used a `SUM` aggregation.
This worked fine up until I applied the following [filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeOp1.png). This filter disorganized my legend:
[image: filter]

Answer (score 1):

In the **Secondary Sort** field, It can be achieved by **EITHER** aggregating the [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) in the question by [`AVG`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583518) **OR** using the [`REGEXP_EXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7050487) function below, in ascending order:

- ***Chart Type***: [Stacked Column Chart](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7165560)
- ***Dimension***: `Date`; Show As: Year Quarter
- ***Breakdown Dimension***: `level of Change impact`
- ***Metric***: `Record Count`
- ***(Primary) Sort***: `Date`; ***Order***: Ascending
- ***Secondary Sort***: `REGEXP_EXTRACT(level of Change impact, R"^(\d)")`; ***Order***: Ascending
- ***Style Tab***: Show Data Labels (Tick)

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/78d87e21-a331-4fa2-8885-812b77988e5d) (Embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PsY_gEJZHtjBKmE5mFEezUJUqS2y2Xjdt8wKbC0sYA8/edit?usp=sharing) Data Source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]